# Size of integers in CPLEX

Tags: linear-programming, cplex, docplex

I tried searching quite a bit but could not find the answer. What is the size of integer variables in CPLEX? Is it 64-bit or is it arbitrary precision based on the bounds?

Comment: Why not try sizeof(IloInt) ?

Comment: @Tryer I work in python and python has arbitrary precision integers. But yeah, I should've looked at the APIs of other languages. That should've cleared it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public  IloIntVar(IloEnv env, IloInt vmin=0, IloInt vmax=IloIntMax, const char * name=0)
```

The Max Value of an integer decision variable is IloIntMax

PS:

```
dvar int x;

subject to
{
  
}

execute
{
  writeln(x.UB);
}
```

gives the exact value

```
2147483647
```

Comment: This is not what is asked by the OP. The question is, what would sizeof(IloInt) return?

Answer (score 0):

code in in concert/include/ilconcert/ilosys.h

```
typedef __int64 IloInt;
typedef unsigned __int64 IloUInt;
typedef long IloInt;
typedef unsigned long IloUInt;
typedef double IloNum;
typedef float IloShortNum;
typedef IloInt IloBool;
typedef void* ILO_MAY_ALIAS IloAny;
typedef IloNum (*IloNumFunction)(IloNum);
```

IloNum is double

IloBool/IloInt both are long